# Which raspberry pi model to use 3.3v to pulse input into 3-6v 2-5A to 400kV piezo transformer?

Tags: gpio

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B07S712WKL/ref=sspa_mw_detail_4?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07S712WKL) Said product, another is practically the same except no clarification on input current. My main question is how I can hook those wires up to the Pi without damaging anything, and if some sort of driver 
While not terribly familiar with electricity and definitely not with the Pi (I know not to plug the 5v into the 3.3v and some cable specs) would a driver be a safe bet for providing that little

Comment: The Pi is irrelevant to this question (which appears to be how do I use the device) and thus the question is off-topic.

Comment: Well, (1) any Rpi model can use a GPIO pin to output 3V High signal.  (2) But You need to read very carefully the user guide if there is any EMI (Electrical Magnetic Inference) which might go back to the Rpi side and fry it.

Comment: I read the spec saying that the input current is at least 2A.  So you need a high power switch, eg power MOSFET IRL540N which can handle big currents.

Comment: WARNING: The front end of your 400kV thing might be a 3V DC to 400 Hertz AC.  The problem is that this front end 400V AC might swing +- 30V pp, even you clamp it to 5V.  So, this initial high spike might fry your rpi: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103868/piezo-sensor-to-pick-up-acoustic-instrument-signal-using-rpi-and-adc

Comment: For Rpi GPIO controlling power MOSFET driving 10A or more load, you might like to read the following post:  Power MOSFET Driving Heavy Load Problem
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94031/power-mosfet-gate-voltage-threshold-puzzle