# Connecting 12V LED to Raspberry Pi GPIO (3.3V)

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, led, breadboard

Currently I am working on RPI GPIO with a breadboard, some LED's and buttons. My next step is to add a bigger button and LED to de GPIO.

I would like to connect an [Eaton 216557 LED-module](https://datasheet.eaton.com/datasheet.php?model=216557) to the GPIO pins of the Raspberry Pi to control it with a python script.

Specs of the LED-module:

**Rated operational voltage [Ue]**: 12 - 30 V AC/DC, 50/60 Hz V

**Rated operational current [Ie ]**: 8 - 15 mA

**Power consumption [Pmax.]**: 0.26 W

Can someone please tell me if this is possible (since RPI is only 3.3V). If it is possible, how can I get it working?

- what kind of resistors
- maybe someone can draw a schematic
- read something about MOSFET ?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Here's [the answer to a similar question.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/112753/83790)

Answer (score 3):

The direct way would be something like this:

[image]

This will work for most purposes. With these currents, you can probably use a 2N3904.

If your power consumption is larger, you may want to look at relais cards.

Or for breadboard users:

[image]

Comment: Is is possible for you to draw a schematic like this for me?:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0pWb.png


An 2N3904 basicly 'connects' the + and - based on the input on the 3th pin?